# WPF Command Binding to ancestor property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a doubt about binding to an ancestor property in WPF. My situation is: my window has a view model as data context with all the commands as ICommand properties. I have a list of checkboxes as follows:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentCustomer.SuppiersSelection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox FontSize="16" Content="{Binding Path=Supplier.Company}" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected}"></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The question is: I want that each checkbox has a command bound to it, so that when a supplier is checked or unchecked the relationship between customer and supplier is automatically saved. My problem is that the command properties are on the Window Data Context and this checkboxes is using as data context the ItemsSource of ItemControl. How do I bind to the property on the Window Data Context?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext}
```

But it's not clear what is the task.
Why don't you use two way binding and process the change of property Selected?

Comment: Hi voroninp, sorry if I'm doing this in a strange way, I'm totally new to WPF and MVVM. I could then directly process the change of property selected directly from the View Model? Can you tell me how do I do that, or where can I read about the matter? I thought the only way to directly process this change was using the code behind. Thanks very much for answering my question.

Comment: It's quite simple. Binding has modes: OneWay,OneWayToSource and TwoWay. When you set TwoWay.State of the bound view goes back to the source property. So you can provide needed logic inside ViewModel's property setter. Commands are used for actions like button clicks.